# How to refresh winform control value use propertymanager?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

i use propertymanager binding Entity to the winform coltrols,but when i set Entity as a anther Entity,coltrol's value not update.here is my code:

```
    private PropertyManager pm;
    txtItemId.DataBindings.Add("Value", Entity, "ItemId",true);
    txtItemName.DataBindings.Add("Text", Entity, "ItemName",true);
    pm=(PropertyManager)this.BindingContext[Entity];    
    void tsBtnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table2QueryForm frm=new Table2QueryForm();          
        frm.ShowDialog();
        if(frm.Tag!=null)
        {
            Entity=(Table2)frm.Tag; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: after Entity=(Table2)frm.Tag,how to make txtItemName's value update??

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use the BindingSource class, below is a sample for your project.

Declare in your form:

```
public BindingSource Source { get; set; }
```

In Form Load event:

```
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I assume that Entity is a variable of type Table2, 
    // if not then change Table2 to any other class
    Source = new BindingSource(typeof(Table2), null);

    txtItemId.DataBindings.Add("Value", Source, "ItemId", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    txtItemName.DataBindings.Add("Text", Source, "ItemName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Handle Button Click event:

```
void tsBtnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Source.DataSource = (Table2)frm.Tag;
}
```